# Python program to simulate inputs to another terminal window

Tags: input, terminal

I'm currently experimenting with python and trying to get more familiar by writing a simple text based game. Obviously this requires testing, and the normal unit test don't seem to work cause I've 're-defined' normal input. Does anyone know of a separate script or method I can use to input a series of commands to my game with a single click, instead of having to walk through the steps each time? How I've 're-defined' input shown in picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAVrf.png)

Comment: "Single click" is confusing. Read about standard input redirection. You can read from stdin in your game, and redirect a file with commands to it: yourgame < yourinput.txt. Something like that. Then you can put the command in a shell script, and "double click" maybe to run the script.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about input-direction and was able to get it working after some research.